# OpenCV Mat data structure

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on OpenCv with C++. I want to declare float Matrices by OpenCV Mat data structure. Does somebody can explain which header file I should use and how I can declare the float Mat with some values.

Answer (score 2):

simply:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
Mat_<float> mat (height, width);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>See the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat)</strike>. (Dead link) There are examples of defining Matrices and using them.

If you include `cv.h` you should be good.

Comment: Documentation contains nothing about headers

Comment: My answer was twofold. I didn't imply that I found the header-inclusion information in the documentation.